# ASP.NET Modal Popup Extender

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a page which uses a modal popup and calls it using the statement:

```
var popUp = 
  window.showModalDialog("../modalPopup.aspx?message="+message, dialogArguments
  , "dialogWidth=850px;dialogHeight=350px;status=no;");
```

I wanted to create a popup and disable or hide the `Close(X)` button in the top right hand corner of the screen. I have already added a link button that closes the window.  Based on my online reading, getting rid of the close button is not posssible using the showModalDialog function. It was suggested that this might be possible using the modal dialog extender.

Before I start adding this extender code, I want to find out if disabling the close button is possible and whats involved. Also, I need to know if there is a way to dynamically add data to a modal popup in javascript...?

Thanks in advance,

GP

Comment: Maybe consider to make an inside "modal window" that you can made with css and make it looks as you like, and avoid this limitations.

Comment: Aristos is right, you just need to change your css to make it look like..

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of javascript modal popups out there. use jquery.
with TINYBox2 http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/

Comment: I would prefer to use the modal popup extender as opposed to jquery if doing it that way is feasible.  Do you know anything about the extender control and if it can be used to create a popup window without an embedded close X button?

Comment: You can't extend the modalpopup directly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JavaScript ModalDialog, You should use [AJAX ModalPopup Extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) as you have asked for doing it with Asp.Net, but if you need some fancy stuff search [Google](http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=jquery%20popup%20exmaples&oq=jquery%20popup%20exmaples&gs_l=hp.3..0i13j0i8i13i30l3.63950.75027.0.75704.35.23.8.4.5.7.701.8510.0j7j5j1j5j4j1.23.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.vCK7obeeO3A&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=8fbb75c76ea4abdd&bpcl=37189454&biw=1280&bih=903) first.
here are the some best plugins using Jquery.

- [LightBox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)
- [Jquery UI Modal Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)
- [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %></pre>

<div class="TextDiv1">
   <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="Panel1_Init" onclick="Panel1_Init">Check Avability</asp:LinkButton>
   <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPE1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" PopupControlID="Panel1" CancelControlID="BtnClose" DropShadow="false">
   </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
</div>
<div class="PopupPanel">
   <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" CssClass="PanelMain" runat="server"
              Style="display: none" oninit="Panel1_Init">
     <div class="PopupText">
      <h1> Check User Name Availability</h1>
          <p class="alert">
          <strong>User name is already used:</strong> The user name you have provided, <b>moizy4u</b>,
                                    is already registered on our web site. Please try a different user name.</p>
                                <div class="c">
                                    <asp:Button ID="BtnClose" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="buttonClass" runat="server" Text="Close" />
            </div>
         </div>
   </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I will try it out. Before with my previous popup I filled it with data using   window.showModalDialog("../modalPopup.aspx?message="+message, dialogArguments
  , "dialogWidth=850px;dialogHeight=350px;status=no;");              Is there any way using the modal popup extender to dynamically add 'message' data using javascript?

Comment: you can use Jquery Ajax and you can call the webservice and populate that through JSON